# Converting from arcgis esri x y coordinates to longitude and latitude in Node.js

Tags: node.js, latitude-longitude, arcgis, esri, geojson

I'm working with a [dataset](https://data.nola.gov/Geographic-Reference/NOLA-Addresses/div8-5v7i) that has X Y coordinates in ArcGIS/esri format. They are akin to `672187.92698, 534175.72095`.

I would like to convert them to longitude latitude so they are more like `'-90.123, 30.456'`.

I've tried a couple npm packages including [esri2geo](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/esri2geo) and [terraformer-arcgis-parser](https://npmjs.org/package/terraformer-arcgis-parser) but these seem to just spit back out the same coordinates. Although with limited documentation not sure using them correctly.

**UPDATE:** while not in Node.js, using external tools I was able to convert my coordinates. See [this GIS Stackexchange Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64535/how-to-convert-x-y-coordinates-to-longitude-latitude-using-quantumgis).

Would still like to know how this conversion could be done within node.js though!

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is project your data to a new coordinate system, not change its format - esri2geo looks like it does the latter, which is why you're just getting the same coordinates back.

According to ArcMap, your data's current coordinate system is:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_Louisiana_South_FIPS_1702_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  3280833.33333333
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -91.33333333
Standard_Parallel_1:    29.30000000
Standard_Parallel_2:    30.70000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 28.50000000
Linear Unit:    Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

...and you want to convert that to, presumably, WGS84.

If this is a one-off job, I would suggest using ArcMap or another GIS package (eg. Quantum GIS) to project the data and save yourself a LOT of pain.

If you have to automate the process, you might have more luck asking about this specific transformation over on [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the info! It is a one-off job. I don't have ArcMap although I do have ArcReader but it cannot seem to open the files. I did get Quantim GIS though!

Comment: Hmm...interesting that ArcReader won't open it, it seems to be a pretty normal shapefile. See the accepted answer in [this thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43848/how-to-re-project-shapefiles) for how to get QGIS to re-project the data.